# SQlite FTS4 Inserting in Virtual table gives error: SQL logic error or missing database

Tags: sqlite

My Virtual table is:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE docs USING fts4(BookID INTEGER, PageNumber INTEGER, PageText TEXT, compress=zip, uncompress=unzip);
```

I insert records in My Virtual table by:

```
INSERT INTO docs SELECT BookID, PageNumber, PageText FROM Books ORDER BY BookID, PageNumber;
```

The Insert command gives this error: SQL logic error or missing database

When I remove compress=zip, uncompress=unzip options from CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE, the problem is solved, why?

Comment: If you are using SQLite with Android, then it won't work because it is not possible define UDF for SQLite on Android (e.g. `zip`).  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353327/sqlite-full-text-search-compression) for more information.

Comment: No, I use SQlite with Windows

Comment: Well can you verify that you have UDFs for `zip` and `unzip` ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How I do this?

Comment: Note that FTS tables do not store numbers. Show the entire error message.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen How I define my own functions for `zip` and `unzip` ?

Comment: @CL. Error massage: SQL logic error or missing database